# How can I test private methods with private return types?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I'm using `PrivateObject` to test private methods in one of my classes (*please, no lectures on not testing private methods.  I have chosen to do it.*)  You can then use `Assert.AreEqual()` to test the return value of your private method... if the return value is a basic built-in type.  But what if my private method is returning a value which itself is a private struct?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestPrivateMethod1() {
    using (Interactors.Interactor interactor = new Interactors.Interactor()) {
        var priv = new PrivateObject(interactor);
        var privateType = priv.Invoke("myPrivateMethod", "foo");
        Assert.AreEqual(12, privateType.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

In this instance the private struct is defined inside the `Interactors.Interactor` class, and is returned into the variable `privateType`.  But since the test method doesn't know about it, I obviously can't compile the code with `privateType.SomeValue` in it.  How can I test that private return type's values?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to use Reflection to get the properties of `privateType` ad then compare it to 12

Comment: Do you have an option of making the method and its return type internal?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It would still be internal to my main class library, not my tests project.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think OP can’t get to reflection yet because his code isn’t compiling.

Comment: But if it were internal you could use the `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute for a friend-assembly, making all internal members and types visible to that friend-assembly.

Comment: Since you went this far using PrivateObject, why not using it to retrieve the value? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.getfieldorproperty?view=mstest-net-1.2.0

Comment: @Jez that’s absolutely right, but there is a solution for internal methods and types that is not available for private methods and types.

Comment: @KevinGosse That gets a field or property but how does it let you test values of a private return type?

Comment: I think the only way is to use reflection to get the members of the private struct and use those in the assert, unless you can´t change the class-structure, which you seem you can not.

Comment: @Jez Just use it to retrieve the value of the `SomeValue` property on your return type. `Assert.AreEqual(12, new PrivateObject(privateType).GetFieldOrProperty("SomeValue"))`

Comment: @KevinGosse Yes!  That worked.  If you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Your question is one of the symptoms and reasons why private methods shouldn't be tested ;)

Comment: @Fabio Except that Kevin came up with a perfectly good answer.

Comment: Unrelated tip: the parameters to `Assert.AreEqual(privateType.SomeValue, 12);` are the wrong way round, as can be seen by the message when the assertion fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrivateObject` uses reflection to manipulate a private type. Just use it to retrieve your value:

```
Assert.AreEqual(12, new PrivateObject(privateType).GetFieldOrProperty("SomeValue"));
```

This is very verbose though. I'm surprised there is no wrapper leveraging the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

And imagine our class has some private type:

```
enum ObjectState { Invalid, Empty, Light, Dark };
```

, and some private method returns a value of this type:

```
ObjectState methodReturningPrivateType (/*some paramethers*/){
   ObjectState retval = Invalid;
   ...
   return retval;
}
```

how would you write Assert statement to check if the method returns ObjectState.Light (for instance)?